# Android ImageView Zooming Effect

Tags: javascript, android, image, zooming

Currently I'm trying to develop an app, where user will be able to zoom in on images. But instead of pinch zoom, I need to make lens effect, which means that when user clicks on image and holds his finger on it for some time, right over it appears circle with zoomed in image. It looks like this:
[image]

I have looked at answers and links provided below and got it like this,  but it's not working:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
ImageView takenPhoto;
static PointF zoomPos;
Paint shaderPaint;
BitmapShader mShader;
BitmapShader shader;
Bitmap bmp;
Bitmap mutableBitmap;
static Matrix matrix;
Canvas canvas;
static Paint mPaint;
static boolean zooming;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/boxes.jpg");

        String fileString = file.getPath();


        takenPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileString);
        mutableBitmap = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        takenPhoto.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);

        matrix = new Matrix();
        mShader = new BitmapShader(mutableBitmap, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP); 
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setShader(mShader);
        takenPhoto.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    private static class ZoomView extends View {



        public ZoomView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }


         public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {


                int action = event.getAction(); 

                zoomPos.x = event.getX();
                zoomPos.y = event.getY();

                switch (action) { 
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    zooming = true;
                    this.invalidate();
                    break; 
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:   
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    zooming = false;
                    this.invalidate();
                    break; 

                default: 
                    break; 
                }



             return true;
         }

         @Override
         protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

             super.onDraw(canvas);

             if (zooming) {
                 matrix.reset();
                 matrix.postScale(2f, 2f, zoomPos.x, zoomPos.y);
                 mPaint.getShader().setLocalMatrix(matrix);

                 canvas.drawCircle(zoomPos.x, zoomPos.y, 100, mPaint);
             }
         }





    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: love the drawing :-)

Comment: theres alot of info and ideas here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902867/how-to-draw-a-circle-after-zoom-in-android

Comment: this question is more or less a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864480/android-how-to-circular-zoom-magnify-part-of-image

Comment: Anyone knows why it works as magnifying "brush effect" and not as lens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite a few days of trying to solve this particular issue, I, thanks to those answers above and other sources, was able to write full working code.

To save time for all of you guys here it is. Copy-paste and edit it a bit to fit your goals.

First of all you need to edit your main activity - we're going to use custom ImageView

```
 <your.package.name.ZoomView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then we'll edit MainActivity.java. Use ZoomView just like ImageView

```
ImageView takenPhoto;
takenPhoto = (ZoomView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

After, create ZoomView class and paste this:

```
public class ZoomView extends ImageView {

PointF zoomPos;
boolean zooming;
Matrix matrix;
BitmapShader mShader;
Paint mPaint;

public ZoomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
    zoomPos = new PointF();
    zoomPos.x = event.getX();
    zoomPos.y = event.getY();

    matrix = new Matrix();
    mShader = new BitmapShader(MainActivity.mutableBitmap, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setShader(mShader);

    int action = event.getAction(); 

    switch (action) { 
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        zooming = true;
        this.invalidate();
        break; 
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
        zooming = false;
        this.invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        zooming = false;
        this.invalidate();
        break; 

    default: 
        break; 
    }
 return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (zooming) {
        matrix.reset();
        matrix.postScale(2f, 2f, zoomPos.x, zoomPos.y);
        mPaint.getShader().setLocalMatrix(matrix);
        canvas.drawCircle(zoomPos.x, zoomPos.y, 100, mPaint);
    }
}
}
```

Now you should have working magnifying effect.

Comment: but then the circle will be always under your finger. If you change its location by changing the zoomPos.x and zoomPos.y  the bitmap will be zoomed in the wrong position.

Answer (score 2):

Well my guess would be :

1- You have to use a touch listener on the imageview
2- You have to have a canvas (where you draw the zoomed bitmap)

If you also want you could implement onDragListener to update the circular zoomed image while you drag your finger across the image.

I would say take a look at this link : [Android - How to circular zoom/magnify part of image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864480/android-how-to-circular-zoom-magnify-part-of-image)

Comment: Hey. I've worked around your answer, it has been very useful. I encountered problem though - nothing happens when I use the exact same code from approved answer from the link. Would you be so kind to check on the code, please? I have updated the question.

Comment: Well check it and get back to you

Comment: For the issue of having the circle move with one finger you have to have onDragListener on the image to be zoomed itself but the effect would be moving a circle. For clearing the drawing you should call Canvas.drawColor(). This method will re-draw every pixel in the canvas to the color you want. This will make the circle disappear.

Comment: onTouchListener works fine. So there's no point in adding onDragListener. when I use Canvas.drawColor(0) or canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) nothing happens - there are still zoom spots

Comment: Did you try adding invalidate?

Comment: Can you show me how are you doing the clearing of the canvas?

Comment: Update in first code snippet of [Update] section. I used canvas.drawColor() when I move and take away the finger

Comment: in the action_up after drawing add the invalidate please

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to write it when was updating the code. Result is the same.

Comment: This is so weird. try adding to action_up

Comment: I played with this. It doesn't work. Try to use it on your phone. I've got most of the code here, so you need to copy paste it. If your approach works for you - that will be weird

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is grabbing the Canvas object from the view where your image in displayed. You will need to update the Canvas using various [motion events](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html).

Within handling these events, use functionality to [draw only a portion of the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504027/draw-only-a-portion-of-a-drawable-bitmap). The method listed is a part of the Canvas object. As far as parameters:

```
Bitmap bitmap   //The image to zoom on
Rectangle src   //A rectangle defining the portion of the image to zoom in on
Rectangle dest  //A rectangle defining where in the View to draw the zoomed portion of your image. 
                //If the size of the rectangles is mismatched, it will zoom.
Paint paint     //The paint object necessary for drawing.
```

Leave a comment if you have any questions. Happy coding!